# In google colab, is there a way to check what TPU verison is running?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

colab offers free TPUs. It's easy to see how many cores are given, but I was wondering if its possible to see how much memory per core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know we don't have an Tensorflow op or similar for accessing memory info, though in XRT we do. In the meantime, would something like the following snippet work?

```
import os
from tensorflow.python.profiler import profiler_client

tpu_profile_service_address = os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'].replace('8470', '8466')
print(profiler_client.monitor(tpu_profile_service_address, 100, 2))
```

Output looks like:

```
  Timestamp: 22:23:03
  TPU type: TPU v2
  Utilization of TPU Matrix Units (higher is better): 0.000%
```

TPUv2 has 8GB per-core and TPUv3 has 16GB HBM per-core (https://cloud.google.com/tpu).

Comment: How do you check the number of available TPU cores?

Comment: If you're using JAX, then you can use `jax.devices()` to get the number of TPU cores (or devices, more generally).